# Finding strings with embedded spaces in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to find a way to figure out the values with embedded spaces in a column. 
Example :

```
Table : Test

COLUMN

ABC       -- OK

A B C     -- OK (only one space between word)

A  B  C   -- (fetch this)(2 spaces)

A   B   C -- (fetch this)(3 spaces)
```

As the last 2 values in the column having embedded spaces, somehow I have to fetch these values..

Any suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select *
from test t
where column like '%  %';
```

Note there are two spaces between the wildcards.